# Prepositions when referring to time

Tags: prepositions, time

Can I use these shortened expressions without a subject?

- Closed in 10 days after 20.7.
- Closing after 10 days from 20.7.

When I want to say, e.g.: The bank account will be closed after 10 days from 20. July.

Comment: What you *want* to say is actually: *The account will be closed 20 days after [date].* But all of your sentence variations don't address your actual question. Why do you want to drop the subject in the first place? I also note that none of your variations actually *do* drop the preposition, which makes things more confusing.

Comment: Of course, you could also simply say: *Closed 14-8.* (Or whatever date format is to be used.)

Comment: It's not possible for it to already be closed if the date's in the future. And if date's in the past, then it's already closed anyway.